# Creating an array of objects in Python for pygame

Tags: python, arrays, object, pygame

I create the objects

```
class Disk:
def __init__(self,number,colour,position,size):
    self.size = size
    self.colour = colour
    self.number = number
    self.position = position


def Render(self,screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.colour,(self.position,self.size))
```

I am trying to create an array of this object using user input (for right now I am just making my own number)
Colours are a seperate array that I've created (it works)

```
def drawDisk(screen,colours):

    num = 5
    for i in range (num):
         disk[i] = Disk(i,colours[i*num],(0+(i*15),500-(i*50)),(400 -(i*30),50))
    disk[i].Render(screen)
```

My program works except for when I try creating an array of disks and using those disks instead of hard coding each individual disk.

Comment: So what happens when you create a list of `Disk`s?

Comment: It says that "disk" is undefined but I don't understand why

Comment: Where is disk defined?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `disk`. You are trying to simultaneously create the list and the items in it and iterate over it, but haven't actually told Python what `disk` is supposed to be. Try:

```
def drawDisk(screen, colours):
    disk = [Disk(i, colours[i], (0+(i*15), 500-(i*50)), (400 -(i*30), 50))
            for i in range(len(colours))] # create and fill disk
    # list comprehension, equivalent to:
    # disk = []
    # for i in range(len(colours)):
    #     disk.append(Disk(i, colours[i], ...))
    for d in disk:
        d.Render(screen) # use items in disk
    return disk # for use elsewhere
```

Comment: for i in range (num) is giving a list index out of range error

Comment: Is `colours` 25 items long?

Comment: Yea that's what it was, I didn't even notice that

Comment: Ok; edited code assuming that you want one `Disk` per item in `colours`. This removes one of the "magic numbers", which is good.